# How to design a table based on css values set from admin/dashboard

Tags: php, css, jquery

I have created a table at `Single Product Page` via `plugin`.
I want to change the `color`, `border`, `bg-color` etc.. according to the values that the admin will set/enter from `dashboard`.

I have done the following so far.

From the following `form (attached image)`, the admin will choose the `css` values for `table body`, `header` etc.And after hitting the `save` button, all those `css` values will be saved inin `wp_options` as `key value` pair.

**For Example**

```
'table_background_color' => '#ff5'
```

**What I want**

I don't want to get the `wp_option` and then apply that `css design value` for particular element of the `table`, because I have huge form containing a lot of `css` `design` values and applying css inline is kind of messy.

I'm looking for some nice approach to apply those `css` values `(which I have saved in wp_options)` to the table.

How can I apply those saved `css values` from a separate file ?
Any help/recommendation will be highly appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a discussion of a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001922/how-do-you-handle-dynamic-css-in-wordpress).

As in that question, there are a few suggested options, each with their own pros and cons.

For what you describe, it sounds like you might want to consider the idea of generating a CSS file every time the admin changes any settings on this page. This is the fastest option because you don't need to re-do this work on every page load.

I'm not sure if there's an easy way to do this (perhaps someone else will know a way), so if you like that approach it seems like you need to do these steps:

1. Make sure that from PHP you can write to a .css file somewhere. Perhaps make a new plugin for this feature and put the code and generated CSS file in the plugin.
2. Make sure that the .css file can be easily enqueue'd from Wordpress
3. Write a script which takes all of your options from `wp_options` and writes a complete CSS file
4. Hook that script so that it re-generates the CSS every time the admin page is saved.

HTH